# Upgrade 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I want to upgrade my 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS. I have tried update-manager-d , and in update manager settings I have set something like : "Notify when new LTS version...". But I don`t get message that new Ubuntu is available . Update manager shows that no, updates available.

Comment: `sudo -s`, then: `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade -y; do-release-upgrade -d`